# Enable syntax highlighting for Haskell?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Smart Contracts running on Cardano are mainly written using Haskell. Also, the Plutus Pioneer Program brings in a lot of Haskell developers.
So one of the most used, even probably the most used programming language within questions will be Haskell.

Examples of questions that would benefit from **Haskell** syntax highlighting:

- [Hardcoding currency symbol and token name in validator script](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/431/hardcoding-currency-symbol-and-token-name-in-validator-script)
- [Why do we need parameterized contracts? Can't we just use datum?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/510/why-do-we-need-parameterized-contracts-cant-we-just-use-datum)
- [Haskell IDE INLINABLE error help](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/459/haskell-ide-inlinable-error-help)
- [Confused by compilation message in plutus playground (week 5 pioneer program)](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/412/confused-by-compilation-message-in-plutus-playground-week-5-pioneer-program)
- [How can I find the Haskell source code for the sqrt function?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-can-i-find-the-haskell-source-code-for-the-sqrt-function)

Examples of questions that would benefit from **other languages** syntax highlighting:

- [Re-Implementing Policy Hashing in Python](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/486/re-implementing-policy-hashing-in-python)
- [Does the testnet faucet still exist? How to create testnet ADA?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/481/does-the-testnet-faucet-still-exist-how-to-create-testnet-ada)
- [How can metadata.json properties be changed after a token is minted?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/448/how-can-metadata-json-properties-be-changed-after-a-token-is-minted)
- [Problem starting a plutus devcontainer in windows](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/382/problem-starting-a-plutus-devcontainer-in-windows)